# How to configure firebase admin at Django server?

Tags: django, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am trying to add custom token for user authentication (phone number and password) and as per reference documents I would like to configure server to generate custom token.

I have installed, `$ sudo pip install firebase-admin`

and also setup an environment : export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[to json file at my server]"

I am using Django project at my server where i have created all my APIs.

I am stucked at this point where it says to initialize app:
`default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app()`

Where should i write the above statement within Django files? and how should i generate endpoint to get custom token?

Regards,
PD

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install firebase-admin
```

credentials.json file includes some private keys. So, you can’t add to your project directly. If you’re using the git version system and you want to host this file in your project folder, you must add the file name to your “.gitignore”.

Set your operation system environ variable. You can use for MacOSX or Linux distributions; For set a variable in window os (https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

```
$ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/path/to/credentials.json'
```

This part is important, google package (It came with firebase_admin package) looking at some conditions for credentials. One of them is os.environ.get(‘GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS’). If you set this file, than you don’t need to anythig fot initialize firebase. Otherwise you should define manually.

For initial firebase look at. Set up configurations (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize )

Create a file named “firebase.py”.

```
$ touch firebase.py
```

Now we can use the “firebase_admin” package for querying. Our firebase.py seems like;

```
import time
from datetime import timedelta
from uuid import uuid4

from firebase_admin import firestore, initialize_app

__all__ = ['send_to_firebase', 'update_firebase_snapshot']

initialize_app()

def send_to_firebase(raw_notification):
 db = firestore.client()
 start = time.time()
 
db.collection('notifications').document(str(uuid4())).create(raw_notification)
 end = time.time()
 spend_time = timedelta(seconds=end - start)
 return spend_time


def update_firebase_snapshot(snapshot_id):
 start = time.time()
 db = firestore.client()
 db.collection('notifications').document(snapshot_id).update(
    {'is_read': True}
 )
 end = time.time()
 spend_time = timedelta(seconds=end - start)
 return spend_time
```

You Refer this link(https://medium.com/@canadiyaman/how-to-use-firebase-with-django-project-34578516bafe)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check it now.

Comment: This explaination is not for real time database. I am using real time database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem primarily pertains to the IDE. Running the Django project through the terminal, rather than the integrated terminal of VS Code or any other IDE, prevents the issue from occurring.